# How to gradually blur the background?

Tags: background, transparency, autohotkey, blur

I have a GUI like this:

```
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
Gui, Add, Text,, 00:00
WinSet, Transparent, 200
Gui, Show, NoActivate
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to gradually blur the background, from outside to inside? I would like to hide to border of the box. I see nothing helpful in [Gui](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the out of the box commands, you really only have a transparency "slider" as your only tool.

The workaround to get the desired effect is to have a transparent background with a custom transparent image on top. i.e. you create your gradient effect that you want in your picture (e.g. a transparent `.PNG`), and you overlay your controls on top of the picture something like this:

```
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
Gui, Add, Picture, w100 h100 , C:\TransparentBackground.png
Gui, Add, Text,xp10 yp10, 00:00
WinSet, Transparent, 200
Gui, Show, NoActivate
```